# Apache HttpClient - не могу отправить картинку POST запросом на ruCaptha

Tags: httpclient

Нужно использовать сервис ruCaptha для распознавания капчи.
[Описание API на их сайте.](https://rucaptcha.com/api-rucaptcha)

Если кратко, то им нужно POST запросом отправлять картинку закодированную в base64 и потом в URLEncode.

Когда это сделано так

```
String url = "http://rucaptcha.com/in.php";
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

//add reuqest header
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

String urlParameters = "method=base64&key=*****************&"+"body="+img+"&submit=загрузить и получить ID";

// Send post request
con.setDoOutput(true);

try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream())) {
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
}

StringBuffer response;

try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) {
    String inputLine;
    response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
}

resp = response.toString();
resp_code = resp.substring(3);

System.out.println("ID заказа : "+resp_code);
```

То все работает. Но нужно сделать это при помощи Apache HTTP Client 4.5.2. Написал такой код

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://rucaptcha.com/in.php");
java.util.List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>(); 

nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("method", "base64"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", "***********"));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("body", img));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("submit", "загрузить и получить ID"));

httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
httpPost.setConfig(config);


CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

String entityString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

System.out.println(entityString);

resp_code = entityString.substring(3);
    //System.out.println(resp);
System.out.println("ID заказа : "+resp_code);

EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
```

Но получаю ошибку ERROR_IMAGE_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED. Погуглив понял что нужно отправлять POST типа multipart/form-data. Но как это сделать конкретно в данной ситуации?

Comment: В первом примере кода нет никакого multipart/form-data. Полагаю, проблема в том, что во втором фрагменте кода переменная `img` содержит значение, закодированное в base64+url-encode, а должно быть просто base64 (apache httpclient сам делает url-encode).

Answer (score 1):

Вам не нужно URL-кодировать `img` перед передачей в `HttpClient` - это операция для вас будет сделана автоматически за сценой. Уберите URL кодирование для img и всё заработает.

Answer (score 0):

Если еще не нашли ответ, то файл в multipart/form-data в клиенте apache можно добавить вот так:

```
        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(new File("FUBAR"), ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
                .addPart("file", fileBody).build();
        postRequest.setEntity(httpEntity);
        response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```